# Rights question on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a database 1 with a user A with data_reader right on it.

I've got a database 2 with a user B wuth data_reader right on it and no access to database 1.

I need to :

- create a view for B on 2 with a reference on table from 1.
- B does not have to see database 1 (In Management studio)
- B does not have to show the T SQL code for the view, and can only do a select on it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is called "cross-database ownership chaining", and can be a real pain.

The trick is to make sure that the following is set up:

1. Both DB2.View and DB1.Table are *owned* by the same *SQL user* (obviously a user that has access to both databases, usually an admin user like SA).
2. "[Cross-database ownership chaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188694.aspx)" is enabled on the server, or on the databases.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx for a more detailed discussion, and a neat diagram.

Comment: Also very importantly, user B must be a registered user (no further rights required) in database 1, or the rights chain is broken.

Comment: @Neil: not doubting you, but if that's true, the MSDN article is a bit incomplete

Comment: agreed, it neglects to mention this, and it is fundamental.

Comment: OK, i'll try this. Moreover, do you know if it is possible to disallow user B showing the view code ?

Comment: @Guillaume: Unless you grant user B "View Definition" right on the database (or schema or on the view directly), they won't be able to see the TSQL of the view.